# HTML/CSS - Avoiding cell splitting when printing

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

I want to print an HTML table.

Unfortunately, when I do, cells (rows) are often cut between two pages.
Also, browsers seem to trample over the page-break-inside property without any care, so that won't work.

The code in question:

```
<table>
<tr><td colspan="2">HEY YALL!</td></tr>
<tr><td>A!</td><td>B</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry -- I think there is no great way to go here -- the web still isn't made for printing.

One work-around for IE is to emulate version 8, so the `page-break-inside: avoid` will work.  There's also a bit about windows and orphans settings.  More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can also look for HTML+CSS - to - PDF conferters.  I've seen a lot of different implementations of that sort of thing.

One thing I've done in the past also is to change the content-type to .doc and stream the HTML out to MS Word (because that's what my users have, and Word can read HTML now.).  This works OK.

Comment: Good to know that I shouldn't waste my time mashing my head against a brick wall. Thanks anyways :)